# How can I split all values from table [Flutter] [Dart]

Tags: flutter, for-loop, dart

After looking around here on StackOverflow and not finding an answer to my problem I decided to post my problem here.

I want to split the `rdSplited` values one by one but automatically depending on `rdSplited.length`, for example if the value here is `4` I want to split the values of those 4 Strings.

I thought about using `for` here, but I don't really know how I can do it.

The index value that I have interest is [0] because it's the string that I want to use for the button.
These values are supposed to be used to create a clickable list view on a popup.

```
      String responseData = response.body;

      responseData = responseData.replaceAll("\"", "");
      responseData = responseData.replaceAll("}", "");
      responseData = responseData.replaceAll("{", "");
      responseData = responseData.replaceAll("d", "");
      responseData = responseData.replaceAll(":", "");
      
      //split string
      var rdSplited = responseData.split('§');
      var intx = rdSplited.length;
      var intxed = rdSplited[0].split('#');
```

PS: Is there a way to optimize this code to one row instead of 5?

```
      responseData = responseData.replaceAll("\"", "");
      responseData = responseData.replaceAll("}", "");
      responseData = responseData.replaceAll("{", "");
      responseData = responseData.replaceAll("d", "");
      responseData = responseData.replaceAll(":", "");
```

**#Edit 1:** The index value that I talk about [0] is the index that I get after the split `var intxed = rdSplited[0].split('#');`

Answer (score 1):

You can perform `replaceAll` using a regular expression by performing the following:

`responseData = responseData.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'd|\\|}|{|:'),"");`

**example**:

```
String testText = "abcd:efgh:jkl::123456::idk{}idk{hi}\\answering\\";
String replaceText = testText.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'd|\\|}|{|:'),"");

print(replaceText);
```

**output**

`abcefghjkl123456ikikhianswering`

This will reduce the five lines to a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up to finish it easly.

```
for (int i = 0; i < intx; i++) {
        var intxed = rdSplited[i].split('#');
        print(intxed[0]);
        print(intxed[1]);
        print(intxed[2]);
}
```